# Python statmodel coint doesn't give the same p-value as adfuller on OLS residual

Tags: python, cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller

According to Eagle and Granger (1987), if I have 2 time series y1 and y2, we can test their cointegration with the p-value of an ADF stationarity test performed on the OLS residual.

Though, when running statmodels coint function and doing the ADF on OLS residual, I end up with 2 different p-values.

Here is an example :

```
ols_result = linregress(y[0], y[1])  # y_1 = alpha + beta y_0
print('OLS done. Results:')
print(ols_result)


residuals: ts = y[1] - (ols_result.intercept + ols_result.slope * y[0])
df_result = ts.adfuller(residuals, regression='c', autolag='AIC', maxlag=1)
print(df_result)

print('Testing cointegration using coint')
coint_res = coint(y[0], y[1], trend='c', maxlag=1, autolag='AIC', return_results=True)
print(coint_res)
```

This script gives 2 different p-values. What did I miss in my script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the fact that the null distribution and therefore the critical values and the $p$-value of the ADF test depend on whether the original series is considered as given (as in a vanilla unit root test) or estimated (as in the cointegration test). You can think about the latter as a series that is measured with error while the former would be measured without error. When doing the cointegration test, we have to account for the fact that the estimated residual series (based on the *estimated* cointegrating relationship) will be closer to stationarity than the actual, unobserved series (based on the *true* cointegrating relationship)*. Thus we use a different null distribution.

*This is because of the nature of OLS; it estimates the cointegrating relationship to minimize the sum of squared residuals, and that also tends to make the residual series appear more stationary than the actual series is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the "null distribution" ? And I don't understand the difference between "given" residual and "estimated" residual ? 

What I know from OLS is as simple as you just give y1 and y2 and it outputs a slope and an intercept that minimizes the SSE. I don't understand at all your point with 'given' and 'estimated' residual , there are several type of residual in an OLS ? Please detail your answer ?

Comment: @JeremLachkar, I have updated my answer with some more detail. I have not tried to explain all the details (such as what the null distribution of a test statistic is), as that would require quite some elaboration, but you could check this online.

Comment: Thank you I think I get it :)